# Bring control to view

Tags: wpf

Is there an easy/good way to bring control into view (make it visible on screen) ?

So far I have tried to do it manually by walking component trees and invoking relevant methods (`BringIntoView`) and properties (`Visibility`) but it is rather complicated due to multiplicity of base types (`FrameworkElement` vs `FrameworkContentElement`, there is also `Visual3D` and maybe more?), parent relationships (visual, logical, template) and necessity of customized handling of certain types (e.g. `TabItem.IsSelected`, `Expander.IsExpanded` - and ideally that should not assume that control is inside Content). There are probably many edge cases that are not covered by this.

**UPDATE**

The code I'm using currently: https://gist.github.com/2761622

Comment: For me `element.BringIntoView()` and then `element.Focus()` usually works!

Comment: That will almost never work (TabControl, Expander, etc.).

Comment: Thats where the developer should do plumbing! GotFocus is routed event and it bubbles!!!

Comment: Do you suggest using RegisterClassHandler ? This is an Q&A site, please give a full answer instead of more riddles ;)

Comment: So I have created a new attached event (tunneled because it's better to go from the top IMHO) and registered class event handler. But that only covers the tree navigation part. I still need to know how to handle all possible types (is it enough to handle FE,FCE, TabItem and Expander ? I guess not).